# how to select row when an edit button in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have been created gridview with edit,update and delete.

when i select link, particular row will be selected. but when i click edit button, the selected rows didn't select.

May i know, how can i fix this?

Here is my cs file:

```
protected void btnsub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            if (Textid.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
            {

                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure3", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Textid.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Textusername.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", Textclass.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Textsection.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", Textaddress.Text.Trim());
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                GridViewRow gr = GridView1.SelectedRow;
                gr.Cells[1].Text = Textid.Text;
                gr.Cells[2].Text = Textusername.Text;
                gr.Cells[3].Text = Textclass.Text;
                gr.Cells[4].Text = Textsection.Text;
                gr.Cells[5].Text = Textaddress.Text;


            }
            else
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure1", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Textusername.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", Textclass.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Textsection.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", Textaddress.Text.Trim());
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("studententry.aspx");
            }
        }
        protected void btnrst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Textusername.Text = null;
            Textclass.Text = null;
            Textsection.Text = null;
            Textaddress.Text = null;

        }
        protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
            {
                GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;               
                Textid.Text = gr.Cells[1].Text;
                Textusername.Text = gr.Cells[2].Text;
                Textclass.Text = gr.Cells[3].Text;
                Textsection.Text = gr.Cells[4].Text;
                Textaddress.Text = gr.Cells[5].Text;
            }
            else if (e.CommandName == "Deleterow")
            {
                GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;      
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure4", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", gr.Cells[0].Text);
                var id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());                
                GridView1.Rows[id].Visible = false;
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
```

and here is my aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" 
        EnablePersistedSelection="True" BackColor="White">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Class" HeaderText="Class" SortExpression="Class" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Section" HeaderText="Section" 
                SortExpression="Section" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" 
                SortExpression="Address" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
               <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnedit" Text="Edit" CommandName="EditRow"></asp:Button>                    
               </ItemTemplate>
                <ControlStyle BorderColor="#CCFF66" />
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
          <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btndelete" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' CommandName="Deleterow"></asp:Button>                    
               </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>            
        </Columns>
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FF66FF" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

and i checked in design and I'm sure that enable selectedrowbutton is true. When i click edit button, after put breakpoint it shows null value, means, the selectedrow didn't work. Here is my output [screenshot](http://s14.postimg.org/f1sghv7up/untitled.jpg)

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you looking for highlighting the current selected row on button click?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow following three approach to highlight current row on button click.

**Approach 1:**

Adding `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event in gridview markup and code-behind.

**GridView Control Mark-up**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" 
        EnablePersistedSelection="True" BackColor="White"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged = "OnSelectedIndexChanged"
        EnableViewState="true">
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowIndex == GridView1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A1DCF2");
        }
        else
        {
            row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
        }
    }
}
```

But here you will be looping inside gridview till you get the selected row index. This will downgrade the performance.

**Approach 2:**

Following approach is far more better than previous one. Here, you won't be needing to loop just mention following under button click event rest all will be done. I haven't tested this one in IDE and can't guarantee it success.

```
Button btnEdit = Button as sender;
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btnEdit.NamingContainer;
int rowindex = gvr.RowIndex;
if (rowindex == GridView1.SelectedIndex)
{
    gvr.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A1DCF2");
}
else
{
    gvr.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
}
```

**Approach 3:**

Since you are using RowCommand you can apply following:-

```
int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
GridViewRow gvr = GridView1.Rows(rowindex);
if (rowindex == GridView1.SelectedIndex)
{
    gvr.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A1DCF2");
}
else
{
    gvr.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
}
```

Comment: actually select button is working.. but when i click edit button using breakpoint, the selectedrow is null..

Comment: Have you tried using rowcommand the one I mentioned at the end.

Comment: where i can add rowcommend?

Comment: Well leave that one the main reason is your grid is losing the state on postback just add `EnableViewState="true"` on gridview markup and run again.

Comment: still nothing change :(